# How to massively add post-build action in multiple Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Subject is self-explanatory. I'd like to add post-build actions for many Jenkins jobs, instead of configuring one by one. I added `Configuration Slicing` plugin but if I'm not mistaken it doesn't modify post-build actions.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to do this? I have the same use case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) doesn't satisfy your requirments, then you should fall back to SED.

From [Jenkins Issues](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8942):

> You will need to write a script that will loop through your Jenkins
>   jobs and SED the value with a new one then use POST
>   https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218353308-How-to-update-job-config-files-using-the-REST-API-and-cURL
>
> 1. Get current config
>      curl -X GET
>      http://developer:developer@localhost:8080/job/test/config.xml -o
>      mylocalconfig.xml
> 2. Post updated config
>      *curl -X POST   http://developer:developer@localhost:8080/job/test/config.xml*
>      *--data-binary "@mymodifiedlocalconfig.xml"*

For the Pos-build actions is the markups between `<publishers>...</publishers>` in the `config.xml`

Comment: I think Groovy would be more jenkins style, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah that could be a Groovy script.

Comment: any one have groovy script for this?